# Ошибка при подключении из Android к MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Через Android хочу подключиться к базе MySQL. Использую стандартный пример JDBC. 
Нет явной ошибки, точно такой-же код компилирую в IntelliJ - работает.

Ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method void java.sql.Connection.close()' on a null object reference

```
String query = "select count(*) from books";

try {
    // opening database connection to MySQL server
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    // getting Statement object to execute query
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    // executing SELECT query
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        int count = rs.getInt(1);
        text.setText("Total number of books in the table : " + count);
    }
} catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
    sqlEx.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
    try { con.close(); } 
    catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    try { stmt.close(); } 
    catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }                            
    try { rs.close(); } 
    catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Android не поддерживает MySQL из коробки. Советую использовать Realm, будете работать с данными в объектно ориентированном стиле

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать:

1. [Download MySQL JDBC Connector 3.0.17](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/?p=mysql-connector-java-3.0&v=3.0.17)
2. [Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Ответ подсмотрел у англоязычных коллег:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698999/android-studio-connection-mysql

А вообще на Android не работают на прямую с MySQL. Если Вы хотите организовать работу БД в телефоне, то вам необходимо работать с 
[SQLite](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html)

Или еще есть продвинутая технология похожая на Spring Data - [Room](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332562/)